# Is $\overline{z}$ a conformal map?

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the ideia to prove that the anti-holomorphic map $f(z)=\overline{z}$ preserves angles?

Comment: I'm not sure of the answer, but I have seen this exact question in Baidyanath Patra's "Complex Variables and Special Functions"

Comment: Looking at the mixed opinions in the answers, you might want to formulate your question more precisely: Are you talking about signed angles, where the direction of the angle matters and the numerical measure of the angle can be positive or negative? Or are you talking about unsigned angles, where the direction of the angle does not matter and the numerical measure is non-negative?

Answer (score 1):

If $z=re^{i\theta}$, then $\bar z=re^{-i\theta}$.  Thus if the angle between $z_1$ and $z_2$ equals $\theta$, it follows that the angle between $\bar {z_1}$ and $\bar {z_2}$ will be $-\theta$.  Thus $z\to\bar z$ is not conformal.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(z)=\bar z$ is a reflection about the $x$ axis so it preserves angles.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a geometric approach suffices: this map represents the reflection w.r.t. to the $x$-axis, so it is an isometry, hence it preserves angles. (If you really want to show this from a complex analysis point of view: show that the map $f(\bar z)=z$ is holomorphic.)

Also note that $f(z)=\bar z$ is *not* a conformal map. In the definition of a conformal map, one also assumes that the map preserves orientations.